# KeyboardType(.NumericPad) not supporting For WatchOS in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

when ever i tried to show number pad as TextField Input i am getting error in watchOS application

code:

```
TextField("BG Value", text: $text).keyboardType(.numberPad)
```

(OR)

```
TextField("BG Value", text: $text).keyboardType(.decimalPad)
```

Error:

> Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'numberPad' Value of type 'TextField<Text>' has no member 'keyboardType'

numberPad/decimalPad not supporting for apple watchOS

Error:

> 'TextField' has no member 'keyboardType'

Expecting  when i select TextField to enter input will show numberPad

Comment: You can't change keyboard types on watchOS. Use a package like [this](https://github.com/ApplebaumIan/SwiftUI-Apple-Watch-Decimal-Pad) if you want a number keyboard.